Who were the Zentradi created to fightagainst?
According to the 1982 Anime Super Dimension Fortress Macross - and its subsequent sequels and spinoffs - the Zentradi were created by the Protoculture to act as soldiers, and to fight in their stead.
Who were the Zentradi created to fight against, and where is this covered in any canon source?
